# flutter/dart this keyword with getter

Tags: flutter, dart

```
enum CategoryStatus { initial, success, error, loading, selected }

extension CategoryStatusX on CategoryStatus {
  bool get isInitial => this == CategoryStatus.initial;
  bool get isSuccess => this == CategoryStatus.success;
  bool get isError => this == CategoryStatus.error;
  bool get isLoading => this == CategoryStatus.loading;
  bool get isSelected => this == CategoryStatus.selected;
}
```

can anyone explain to me the use of "this" keyword inside the getter.

Answer (score 2):

`this` is referring to the current instance of `CategoryStatus`.

Like if the

```dart
 final data = CategoryStatus.success;
 data.isError; //data is `this`
```

Comment: Thank you @Yeasin , what about '==' sign before the this keyword?

Comment: You're welcome  `==` check left, and right part is same or not. Like in this example `data` means `CategoryStatus.success` , while using   `data.isError` it will check  `bool get isError => CategoryStatus.success == CategoryStatus.error;`    . you can find more about [/extension-methods](https://dart.dev/guides/language/extension-methods)

Comment: I got it, thanks a lot once again.